# hg serve as Windows service

Tags: windows, mercurial, service

I'd like to use mercurial on a Windows server.  Since I want to pull and push via http, `hg serve` seems the easiest solution.  It works fine, but I have restart it after each reboot, so I need it as a Windows service.  Installing it manually with `sc create ...` didn't work, it created a service that throws an error when I attempt to start it.  I found some references to this problem

- https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/1245/configure-hg-serve-to-run-as-a-windows-service-from
- https://bitbucket.org/andrearicossa/hgservice

but they are poorly documented if at all.  (Of course, I could install a web server and use hgweb, but it seems even more complicated.)  Do you have any experience how to set up easily `hg serve ... <many args>` as a Windows service?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the different approaches.  We stayed with `hg serve`, the windows-guy at our company managed to install it as a not-quite-proper service.

Comment: Jeff's [sc create for svnserve example](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/04/setting-up-subversion-on-windows.html) on codinghorror worked for me, and there's multiple args in there - you might be able to use that as a template. After I'd figured out that sc is very picky about spaces between `abc= value` that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out [Jerremy Skinner his blogpost](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/mercurial-on-iis7/) on this subject. He explains how you can host Mercurial repositories on IIS7 and use some nice url-routing.
I did it on my machine and it works like a charm. It takes some configuration, but it's worth it.

1 error in his post I noticed was that he's writing about a *hgwebdir.cgi*, but I couldn't find that one. I did find a *hgweb.cgi*, so did the copy-pasting with this file.

Comment: hgwebdir.cgi was renamed to hgweb.cgi with revision 1.6.

Answer (score 5):

Or you could use the [SCM-Manager](https://github.com/scm-manager/scm-manager)

Comment: This is so far the easiest method for serving up HG repositories I've tried on Windows. The start up bat file has an install parameter that will install the app as a windows service. Very nice.

Answer (score 5):

Using a web server such as apache/lighttpd/iis gives a lot of features such as authentication or HTTPS support. But 'hg serve' is a simple and fast solution. Furthermore, 'hg serve' can serve multiple repositories. But hg serve cannot itself be run as a Windows service because it cannot respond to the Windows control commands. So using [HgService](https://bitbucket.org/andrearicossa/hgservice)  is a good solution to make 'hg serve' a real Windows service.

Here is an example of my configuration. I followed following steps:

- Install TortoiseHG
- Install HgService
- Create "C:\Repositories" folder and put needed repos into it.
- Create "C:\Repositories\hgweb.config" with following contents:

```
[paths]
/ = C:\Repositories\*

[web]
style = monoblue
```

- Modify HgService.exe.config in C:\Program Files\Mercurial\HgService

```
<add key="CommandLine" value="hg.exe"/>
<add key="CommandLineArguments" value="serve --prefix=/hg --address 0.0.0.0 --port 80 --web-conf c:\Repositories\hgweb.config -A access.log -E error.log" />
```

- Start the service

Hope this sequence of action will be helpful to you also.

Answer (score 2):

An Apache-based alternative: [HgServe - Mercurial Repository Server for Windows on Apache](https://bitbucket.org/archer256/hgserve/overview)

Answer (score 1):

hg serve works fine with [NSSM](http://nssm.cc/) !